# How to concatenate some columns with another columns in loop in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, concatenation, nan

Here I have dataframe DF in which I have to concatenate 3 columns 1A,1B and 1C with 2 columns 2P and 2Q so that I get the OUTPUT column as array or list of concatenated elements.

- For example, if all the elements in all the columns from A to E are present then output column will contain total 3*2=6 elements.
  -At least one of the columns 1 and 2 must be present for the output otherwise there won't be any output.
  -Here we don't need to do anything with column 3.
  -We need to take only alphanumeric characters.
  -Given is the dataset and desired output.

  ```
        1A      1B     1C      2P      2Q    3A       3B    Output
       1RU4    DGHJ   9087.0  WERT    POUO   qwe     1234
       3456OO  89AS    NaN   3478-A   YU 89  qohg34   NaN 
        23ERT   ASD    56.0   56+RT   NaN     899     90
        NaN    345TY   NaN     NaN    7890    ABC     opu
        NaN     NaN    NaN    6789     NaN    ert     OUB
        34567   NaN    ASDF    NaN     NaN    NaN     POU


    Output
    ["1RU4|WERT","1RU4|POUO","DGHJ||WERT","DGHJ||WERT","9087|WERT","9087|WERT"]
    ["3456OO|3478A","3456OO|YU89","89AS|3478A","89AS|YU89"]
    ["23ERT|","ASD|56+RT",56|56RT"]
    ["345TY|7890"]
    NaN
    NaN
  ```

When there was just one column1A and three column 2A,2B and 2C,I was using following code but now I don't know how to change it so that it also loop through column 1s.Could you help in how to change this or is there any better way to do this?

```
 s = (df['1A'].str.replace('\W','')+ '|')

 #all another columns convert to strings, replace and add to s
 f = lambda x: s + x.astype(str).replace({'^nan$':None, '\.0$':''}, regex=True)
          
  #for column filtered by name ('2') add values to list
   df1 = (df.filter(like='2').apply(f)
      .stack()
      .groupby(level=0)
      .agg(list)
      .to_frame('Output'))
   df=pd.concat([df,df1],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "1A": ["test1Aa", "test1Ab", "test1Av"],
        "1B": ["test1Ba", "test1Bb", "test1Bc"],
        "1C": ["test1Ca", "test1Cb", "test1Cc"],
        "2P": ["test2Pa", "test2Pb", "test2Pc"],
        "2Q": ["test2Qa", "test2Qb", "test2Qc"],
        "3A": ["test3Aa", "test3Ab", "test3Ac"]
    }
)
```

which looks like:

```
        1A       1B       1C       2P       2Q       3A
0  test1Aa  test1Ba  test1Ca  test2Pa  test2Qa  test3Aa
1  test1Ab  test1Bb  test1Cb  test2Pb  test2Qb  test3Ab
2  test1Av  test1Bc  test1Cc  test2Pc  test2Qc  test3Ac
```

You can loop through the first columns you want (1A, 1B, 1C) and then loop through the second columns you want (2P, 2Q, 3A) and create a new column with the string you want. For example while looping `1A` and `2Q`, you will create the column `1A|2Q`. This can be done like:

```
# new columns that will be created
new_cols = []
for col in ["1A", "1B", "1C"]:
    for col2 in ["2P", "2Q", "3A"]:
        df[col + "|" + col2] = df[col] + "|" + df[col2]
        new_cols.append(col + "|" + col2)
```

and will result in:

```
          1A       1B       1C       2P       2Q       3A            1A|2P            1A|2Q            1A|3A            1B|2P            1B|2Q            1B|3A            1C|2P            1C|2Q            1C|3A
0  test1Aa  test1Ba  test1Ca  test2Pa  test2Qa  test3Aa  test1Aa|test2Pa  test1Aa|test2Qa  test1Aa|test3Aa  test1Ba|test2Pa  test1Ba|test2Qa  test1Ba|test3Aa  test1Ca|test2Pa  test1Ca|test2Qa  test1Ca|test3Aa
1  test1Ab  test1Bb  test1Cb  test2Pb  test2Qb  test3Ab  test1Ab|test2Pb  test1Ab|test2Qb  test1Ab|test3Ab  test1Bb|test2Pb  test1Bb|test2Qb  test1Bb|test3Ab  test1Cb|test2Pb  test1Cb|test2Qb  test1Cb|test3Ab
2  test1Av  test1Bc  test1Cc  test2Pc  test2Qc  test3Ac  test1Av|test2Pc  test1Av|test2Qc  test1Av|test3Ac  test1Bc|test2Pc  test1Bc|test2Qc  test1Bc|test3Ac  test1Cc|test2Pc  test1Cc|test2Qc  test1Cc|test3Ac
```

You can get them as an array with:

```
df[new_cols].values
```

Comment: Hey thanks.Is is possible to directly get that list of lists columns without getting any other column added?

Comment: edited it, so as to get only the new columns

Comment: No I mean only one columns added to old dataframe which contain the list/array of all